# Angular Google maps - running custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am using Angular google maps and my map and marker data is getting loaded properly. When you click on the marker some profile data is loaded:

[image]

The profile image has a directive that should add a fall back image if the actual profile image does not exist. However, the directive is not run at all and so no fall back image is provided. Here's the html:

```
<img src="https://localhost/manager/photo/?repId=123" fallback-src="https://localhost/styles/core/images/avatarprofile.svg" class="photoImg">
```

The directive is working on my own pages, just not on the angular google map. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular google map is just a wrapper on google map. It will not compile your tooltip html. It will just inject it.

So your directive will not work in angular google map tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Is there a way I can explicitly compile it?